# Is there any php plugin that eliminates the need in php to prefix variables with the $ sign

Tags: php

After programming eight years in php i'm getting quite sick of every time having to put for no reason SHIFT + 4 whenever i put a variable somewhere. I've looked on the internet but the only thing i found was a feature request: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54325 Is there any plugin that can be installed or some other way that allows you to put variables like any other programming language. I don't know how to ask this more constructively and i couldn't find any existing question for this. I'm not asking why there's a dollar sign. Of course I know it's  inherited from PERL

Comment: The feature request said "a waste of precious keystrokes". I don't think so. I have been pressing SHIFT+4 for `$` over 7 years. I don't feel like that. If you keep in touch with keystrokes daily, it won't be a problem.

Comment: @Sithu unless when you also program in other languages like java and C# and then move back to php and later notice something isn't working because you forgot to put the dollar sign somewhere.

Comment: @lAwaysAcceptAnswer please also think of vice-versa. As for me, when I program in other languages, it is strange when I don't see any prefix to variables :P

Comment: One thing you could look for is getting your favorite editor to input the dollar sign for you. Unlike the php runtime, your editor is clearly your own, so you won't bother any other users, you can fix it when your editor gets it wrong. I still don't think it exists, but even then it will be easier to make than php modifications/plugins or whatever.

Comment: @Jasper An editor that automatically puts the dollar sign would indeed be nice. I'm using Sublime Text 2, unfortunately it doesn't have it. Maybe a good idea to send them a feature request about it.

Comment: @IAlwaysAcceptAnswer I don't think they would give such a request would get a high priority from the developers of that software. Your best bet would be one of (a) an editor with sufficient plugin capabilities so you can write your plugin for this (b) using an editor that has scripting capabilities (things like vim offer a lot of customization) or (c) an open source editor you can modify yourself to add this functionality

Comment: The answer is no. The suggestion a plugin could be fashioned so your editor could take care of it is fanciful. Think about it, everything is just a string, how would you differentiate between a constant, a function or method name or an actual variable? You'd need to indicate it is a variable to begin with, and for that we already have `$`.

Comment: Just wait until you have to keep typing `self::` and `$this->` everywhere ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't. That's a basic construct of the language that you can't get around.